# When giving date all the files in the date should display

Tags: django-models, django-templates, django-views

while entering the date and submitting,all the files which is in the entered date should display.as i am new to django plz guide me

Different pdf file with different date is stored in table.While entering the date,after submitting,all the files in the entered date should list.
views.py

```
def select_date(request):
    client = Client.objects.all()
    process = Client_Process.objects.all()
    pdf = Client_files.objects.all()
    obj1 = Client_files.objects.values_list('id', 'Date')
    if request.method == "POST":
        fromdate = request.POST['fromdate']


    return render(request,'select_date.html', {'pdf':pdf,'client':client,'process':process})

models.py
class Client_files(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    client_process = models.ForeignKey(Client_Process, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    File_Name = models.FileField()
    Pages = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Status = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    class Meta:
        db_table : 'client_files'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter it using [gte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#gte) (greater than or equal to)

```
if request.method == "POST":
    fromdate = request.POST['fromdate']
    pdf = Client_files.objects.filter(Date__gte=fromdate)
```

or if you just want to filter equal date, use this instead:

```
pdf = Client_files.objects.filter(Date=fromdate)
```